# Async Await in Lambda expression where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asynchronous, lambda

I would want to call an async method inside lambda expression. Please help me doing the below

eg -

```
return xyz.Where(async x=> await AsyncMethodCall(x.val));
```

And the Async method looks like

```
public async Task<bool> AsyncMethodCall(Data d){...}
```

When I do the above, I get the following error

> Error CS4010  Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type
>   `'Func<Data, bool>'`. An async lambda expression may return `void`, `Task`
>   or `Task<T>`, none of which are convertible to `'Func<Data, bool>'`.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Where is a *filter*. It's supposed to *filter* things, not make random changes. Why are you using an asynchronous method in it? Are you using it as if it were a *Select* statement?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos For example it could call a web service, or access a DB... The question is good... You can't do it, and even if you could it wouldn't probably be a good idea, but that is another problem...

Comment: @xanatos the fact it's a bad idea is probably why you can't do it, ie why there is no `Where()` method that accepts a Task

Comment: In general `async` and `IEnumerable<>` don't mix, because `Task` (the class at the base of `async`) presuppose that the result it contains can be used only when it is `Completed`... but here you have that the pieces of the result (the single `xyz` elements) can be enumerated "during" the lifetime of the `Task`, and the `Task` is `Completed` when there are no more elements.

Comment: Your `async` and `await` cancel each other out. The same but simpler: `.Where(x => AsyncMethodCall(x.val))`. This should give you the same error, the `Where()` extensions method doesn't accept awaitables.

Comment: You want something similar to https://asyncenum.codeplex.com/ or https://github.com/tyrotoxin/AsyncEnumerable

Comment: @ArthiSivakumar what are you trying to do? What does `AsyncMethodCall` do and how are you using this query?

Answer (score 20):

Asynchronous sequences are tricky because you really have to think about what *specifically* you want the code to do.

For example, you could want to execute the `AsyncMethodCall` calls sequentially, and then return all the results:

```
var result = new List<T>();
foreach (var d in xyz)
  if (await AsyncMethodCall(d.val))
    result.Add(d);
return result;
```

Or, you could execute all the `AsyncMethodCall` calls concurrently, and then collect and return the results (again, all at once):

```
var tasks = xyz.Select(async d => new { d, filter = await AsyncMethodCall(d.val) });
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
return results.Where(x => x.filter).Select(x => x.d);
```

Or, you could execute all the `AsyncMethodCall` calls sequentially, and produce the results one at a time. This approach is incompatible with `IEnumerable<T>` (assuming you want to keep the call asynchronous). If you want to produce a sequence where `AsyncMethodCall` is asynchronously invoked during sequence enumeration, then you would need to change to `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. If you want to produce a sequence that is *started* by the consumer and then produces results on its own, you would need to change to `IObservable<T>`.

Or, you could execute all the `AsyncMethodCall` calls concurrently, and produce the results one at a time. This is also incompatible with `IEnumerable<T>`; you would need to change to `IObservable<T>`. And you would also need to decide whether to maintain the original ordering, or to produce them in order of `AsyncMethodCall` completing.